# how to write serializer for embbed hasmany relationship in ember-data upon obtaining JSON response

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have this question model:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  subjects: DS.hasMany('subject', {embedded: 'always')
});

App.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
  description: DS.attr('string')
  question: DS.belongsTo('question')
});

App.QuestionAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

App.QuestionSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id',  
  serializeId: function(id) {
    return id.toString();
  }
});
```

and this is my data sample:

```
{
    "questions": 
    [{
        "_OwnerId": "53e440b3b6d1de0b3cc12b44",
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "53f03ac07295ef2b467551d9",
        "description": "0987654321",
        "subjects": [{"description":"cs", "question":"53f03ac07295ef2b467551d9" },
{"description":"physics","question":"53f03ac07295ef2b467551d9" }],
        "title": "2134567890"
    }]

}
```

All my code works fine without subjects area. I believe I have to override addhasmany or serializeHasMany in which I don't know the different between the two. But is the way I set up the JSON correct, and how would I write a serializer to serialize the subjects area correctly?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html you should be able to configure it easily to serialize and deserialize embedded relationships. Look at the `'embedded' : 'always'` option from the first example

Comment: I ended up using new kind of formatted JSON which has all the data  embedded, and rewrite serializer with extractArray overrided. Marked this one as answer since it seems to be a legitimate solution.